# Сортировка строки двумерного массива

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка, указатели

Задача: Написать функцию которая принимает указатель на двумерный массив , количество строк, количество столбцов и строку `k` которую нужно отсортировать по возрастанию.

Передать-то я вроде смог, но что я передал и что с ним делать - не знаю.

```
int n, m, k;
cout << " Enter N,M,K: " << endl;
cin >> n >> m >> k;
int** p = new int*[m];
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    p[i] = new int[n];
}
InputTwoArray(p,m,n); //ввод матрицы
PrintMatrix(p, m, n); //вывод на консоль
SortLine(*(p+k-1),  n); //сама сортировка
```

Вот сама функция частично переделанная, но я считаю, что она абсолютно не верна. Объясните пожалуйста как сделать и, по возможности, с кодом.

```
void SortLine(int *arr, int n) {//сортировка
int k = *arr - 1;
for (int j = n; j > n; j--)
    if (arr[n] < arr[n])
    {
        int tmp = arr[n];
        arr[n] = arr[n];
        arr[n] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Давайте покажете полное задание и скажите, можно ли использовать с++, или нужно писать на сиподобном с++. В любом случае, сортировка строки неверно написана.

Comment: Разработайте библиотеку функций для работы с прямоугольными матрицами целочисленных значений размерности nxm (n,m<=10). Реализацию функций разместите в файлах исходного кода Matrix.cpp, интерфейс функций - в Matrix.h. В состав библиотеки включите следующие функции:
сортировка элементов k-ой строки матрицы по возрастанию (любым известным вам алгоритмом)

всю делается на с++. у меня вижуал студия 2017.
А можете объяснить сортировку, как правильно сделеать??)

Comment: сортировка делается функцией std::sort + правильный компаратор

Comment: Можно на примере? или ссылку хотя бы

Comment: + ещё тут нужно отдельную ф-ую создать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
void sort(int* arr, unsigned int m)
{
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i < m; i++)
      for (unsigned int j = 1; j < m; j++)
        if (arr[j] < arr[j-1])
        {
            int tmp = arr[j-1];
            arr[j-1] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = tmp;
        }
}

void sort(int** matrix, unsigned int n, unsigned int m, unsigned int k)
{
    if (!matrix)
        return;

    if (k >= n)//Номер строки не корректен
        return;

    if (!matrix[k])
        return;

    sort(matrix[k], m);
}
```

Comment: Идеально, долго не мог её решить, но можно было и без usigned, там же всё равно меньше нуля не будет)

Comment: а зачем цикл ещё один с i?

Comment: 1)unsigned int как раз именно потому, что индекс меньше нуля не имеет смысла. 2)  Это сортировка пузырьком, при `i = 0` внутренний цикл выталкивает самый большой элемент,  при `i = 0` выталкивает следующий самый большой элемент и ставит его на предпоследнее место, при i = m все элементы упорядочены

Comment: Upd^ Всё понял, всё отлично